# R - merge column values

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have an input dataframe as below:

```
COL1    COL2
10     res prt
10     res
10     kitty
10     dog 
10     kitty cat
10     doggy dog
```

I want the output to be like this:i.e COL2 should contain non-repetitive concatenated values

```
COL1    COL2
10  res prt, kitty, dog, cat, doggy
```

Please someone help me with this as I'm a novice to R

Comment: Is 10 the only entry? if not, please modify your example

Comment: Yes.. 10 is the only entry

Comment: Please clarify: In your first entry you have "res prt", second entry "res", 5th entry "kitty cat". In your desired output you have "res prt", no "prt" and then "kitty" and "cat" are separate. Is this how you would like your data to be?

Answer (score 1):

If `10` is the only entry, then :

```
> new.df <- data.frame(COL1 = 10, COL2 = paste(unique(unlist(strsplit(paste(df$COL2), split = " "))), collapse = " "))
```

> Result :

```
> new.df
  COL1                        COL2
1   10 res prt kitty dog cat doggy
```

**EDIT:**

To get the exact answer, try this **dumb** brute(cause every `for` in R is considered wrong, I think) `brute force` solution:

```
> str <- paste(df$COL2)
> str
[1] "res prt"   "res"       "kitty"     "dog"       "kitty cat" "doggy dog"

> for(i in 2:length(str)) {
     Remaining.Words <- unlist(strsplit(str[1:i-1], split = " "))

     My.Words <- unlist(strsplit(str[i], split = " "))

     for(k in 1:length(My.Words)) {
         if(My.Words[k] %in% Remaining.Words) My.Words <- My.Words[-k]
     }

     if(length(My.Words) > 0) str[i] <- paste(My.Words, collapse = " ")
     else str <- str[-i]
 }
> str
[1] "res prt" "kitty"   "dog"     "cat"     "doggy"   "NA"     
> new.df <- data.frame(COL1 = 10, COL2 = paste(str[-6], collapse = ","))
```

> Result_2.0 :

```
> new.df
  COL1                        COL2
1   10 res prt,kitty,dog,cat,doggy
```

Comment: yeah, that would be my answer too, but he wants commas, so `collapse` should be a comma

Comment: Still, there's a lot more to do. The demo above indicates that :

 - `res prt` comes first, then ignore `res`
 - `dog` comes first, then delete `dog` in `doggy dog`

Any idea ? @Amit Kohli

Comment: Yes..I do not want to split the field into individual words. Instead, I want the whole field to be considered as one.. Can anyone suggest a solution using the gsub or grepl commands???

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick example:

```
# a text column
txt <- c("foo bar", "bar", "foo")

# split it into words
words <- unlist(strsplit(txt, " "))

# return the unique values of this
unique(words)
[1] "foo" "bar"
```

Make sense? if you wanted to print them out concatenated, you could then say:

```
cat(unique(words))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dplyr for that, try:

```
df <- data.frame(COL1 = c(rep(10, 4), rep(20, 3)),
                 COL2 = c("res prt", "res", "kitty", "kitty cat",
                          "res", "kitty", "kitty cat"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
##  COL1      COL2
## 1   10   res prt
## 2   10       res
## 3   10     kitty
## 4   10 kitty cat
## 5   20       res
## 6   20     kitty
## 7   20 kitty cat

library(dplyr)
makeString <- function(x) {
  res <- unlist(strsplit(x, " "))
  res <- unique(res)
  paste(res, collapse = ", ")
}

df %>%  group_by(COL1) %>% summarise_all(makeString)
```

This gives you:

```
## A tibble: 2 × 2
##   COL1                 COL2
##  <dbl>                <chr>
## 1    10 res, prt, kitty, cat
## 2    20      res, kitty, cat
```